# Copied Tomcat 6 webapp working fine on one server to another Tomcat 6 server get Null component error

Tags: java, tomcat

I am running tomcat 6, 64 bit on a Windows 7 64 bit platform.  I copied my web application (entire folder - it is called cuba4remedy) to a tomcat 6 64 bit installation on a different machine.  this one running Windows 2008 standard 64 bit.

The servlet was working fine on my Windows 7 development machine but when I run on the new machine I see this error in the Catalinaxxx.log :-

SEVERE: Null component Catalina:type=JspMonitor,name=jsp,WebModule=//localhost/myappnamehere,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none

I don't really understand why I am getting this error.  Any ideas anyone?

One more point might be relevant.  I compiled on my dev machine using Javac version 1.7.  On the machine I copied to only the Java runtime is installed - that is Java version 1.6.

EDIT
For anyone else facing this problem, it seems that dev version of Java must be either same or lower version than deployment.  I downgraded my dev java version to same as target runtime version and then this error went away.  Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: see this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648758/severe-null-component-catalinatype-jspmonitor-name-jsp-webmodule-localhost-m

Comment: Can you tell us the tomcat version on your dev machine on the server? Is the tomcat on the server already running other applications or just yours?

Comment: Just use the `-target 1.6` parameter when you compile for a JDK 1.6. Otherwise (as it's expected) java 7 will compile for a java 7 runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile with J7 and deploy on J7. Just use the parameter [`-target 1.6`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) when you compile for a JDK 1.6. Otherwise (as it's expected) java 7 will compile for a java 7 runtime.